# Set the current place on google place api

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-places-api

I'm trying to search places (like restaurants or hotels) around a `Latlng` using `google place` api's. Is there any possibility to change the result of    `Places.PlaceDetectionApi getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, pf);`    and set other coordinate. My code is:

```
     mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();


    ArrayList<String> restrictToRestaurants = new ArrayList<>();
    restrictToRestaurants.add(Integer.toString(Place.TYPE_RESTAURANT));
    PlaceFilter pf;
    pf = new PlaceFilter(false, restrictToRestaurants);

    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, pf);

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            final CharSequence thirdPartyAttributions = likelyPlaces.getAttributions();
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                Log.i("tag", String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
                        placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                        placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));


            }
            likelyPlaces.release();
        }
    });
```

So I have a variable `Latlng` and I want to search places nearly that coordinate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After read more the Google Place API I understand that there's no way to do this (its only used to find places nearby the device location :( )... As a suggestion maybe people of Google could develop a function that giving a  location retrieve the places nearly that location :) (sorry about my english, is so bad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can always use [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search), which looks something like this:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&keyword=cruise&key=API_KEY`
where

> location — The latitude/longitude around which to retrieve place information. This must be specified as latitude,longitude.

Comment: Since you are at a Android device: "The Google Places API Web Service is for use in server applications. If you're building a client-side application, take a look at the Google Places API for Android and the Places Library in the Google Maps JavaScript API.". Source: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests